# Unable to find template symfony3

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm doing a project as a web dev student on symfony3.
I've been looking for similar errors, but i cant get the solution for mine.
I have a problem when im trying to load a twig template, the error is the next one:

> Unable to find template "ForoBundle:Usuario:prueba.html.twig" (looked into: D:\xampp\htdocs\dawSymfony\app/Resources/views, D:\xampp\htdocs\dawSymfony\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bridge\Twig/Resources/views/Form)

I dont get it, can you help me out?

My routes:

```
foro_homepage:
    path:     /foro
    defaults: { _controller: ForoBundle:Default:index }


foro_prueba:
    path:    /prueba
    defaults: { _controller: ForoBundle:Default:prueba }
```

My action:

```
public function pruebaAction(){
    return $this->render("@Foro:Usuario:prueba.html.twig");

}
```

[Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nd6cF.png)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code should look like that:

```
$this->render("@Foro/Usuario/prueba.html.twig");
```

Check the [doc](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/templating.html#referencing-templates-in-a-bundle).

You should be using **slashes** and bundle name without word "Bundle".